# AWS Account Limits - ruby sdk api query

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I use AWS extensively and often ask them to increase our accounts' limits. I'd like to know I'm about to hit a limit before it happens,

Limits for EC2 and IAM are easy:

```
ec2_acc = AWS::EC2::Client.new(region: "us-east-1")
atr = ec2_acc.describe_account_attributes[:account_attribute_set] # includes limits
iam = AWS::IAM.new
iam_acc = iam.account_summary # description includes limits
```

**Anyone knows how to get the limits for: RDS, EBS, EC2::ELB?**

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no API method to get RDS/EBS..etc. limits.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks slayedbylucifer,

Amazon confirmed this, and said to keep an eye on: http://aws.amazon.com/new/